# Why am I getting a file path when hovering over icon in MS Word Document?

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, icons, print-to-pdf

I pasted some icons onto my resume which I made in MS Word. I also attached web links to each of them (which work perfectly).
But, when I hover onto these links, I get a pop-up indicating the file-path of those icons on my PC. How to avoid this ?

[image: This is what the pop-up looks like]

Comment: "How to avoid this ?" - You need to embed the image in the document instead of doing what ever operation you performed (not clear by your description)

Comment: What exactly do you mean? @Ramhound
I had copied the image and then pasted it into my Word Doc.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the file location is written to the Alt-text of the image. Right click on the image to access Image properties and find Alt-text. Not sure of any way to turn this off but one way to avoid it is to copy and paste the image from an image editor into Word.